# Got ArrayStoreException when trying to instantiate a multi-dimensional array (3D array)

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, multidimensional-array

```
resultList = [[[Computer lessons], [Leon, Maria]], [[Computer repair], [Jack, Leon]], [[Data recovery service], [Leon]], [[Handyman], [Jack]], [[House cleaning], [Jack, Maria]]]

String[][][] result = new String [resultList.size()][][];

int count = 0;
for(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> nestedList:resultList) {

   result[count]= nestedList.stream().map(List::toArray).toArray(String[][]::new);
   count ++;
}
```

The code above initializes an `ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>` with some values. then tries to put its content in a 3-dimensional String Array.(`String [][][]`). The code generates the following exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Please advise.

Comment: `new String[resultList.size()][][]` is your problem. The last two brackets are empty, and thus have a length of `0` and can't store anything.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it up:

```
    nestedList.stream().map(List::toArray)
```

As per its definition, `nestedList` is an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.

Therefore, `nestedList.stream()` is a Stream of `ArrayList<String>`.

And `.map(List::toArray)` applies the `toArray()` method on each `ArrayList<String>` to turn it into a stream of `Object[]` arrays. There's your problem. You are using the [toArray()](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray--) method without arguments, which returns an Object array instead of a String array. You need instead to use the [toArray(String[])](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) method.

```
.map(list -> list.toArray(new String[list.size()]))
```